# Get file name if have part of it - PHP

Tags: php, regex

OK, so, I need to get file name from directory if I have part of it's file name. Example:

```
directory/
 - filename1.dat1
 - otherfile2.dat2
 - thirdfile.dat3
```

And I want to get name of file if I have extension (dat1, dat2, ...). 
If you can't understand me, again, I have "dat3" and want to get the file name that contains that extension.

2nd example:

```
<?php
   $dat_extension = "dat3";
   $file_name = getFileName($dat_extension); // something like this
   echo $file_name; // returns thirdfile.dat3
 ?>
```

Comment: How about the `glob()` function?

Comment: And how about `fnmatch()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$array = array();
$files = scandir('dir/');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if($ext == 'dat3'){
        array_push($array, $file);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$dir = "directory";

foreach(glob($dir . '/*.dat3') as $file) 
{
    echo $file;
}
```